# Live video streaming using gstreamer display on web browser

Tags: browser, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I am trying send h264 video in UDP packeted using gstreamer. 
Like,
gstreamer v4l2src ! video/x-raw-rgb, widht=320, height=240 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.1 port=12345
Can someone tell me how to receive video on receiver side display on web browser..? 
Thanks in advance..

Pra-win

Comment: try for a pipeline on the lines of : udpsrc -> avdec_h264 -> autovideosink. in your case you need to find a way to direct the output of a sink to a browser.